# How to pass in authentication in download link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a regular hyperlink in html that points to foo.com/foo.mp3, but to access the site I need to pass in authentication in the header of the request. How do I do that?

Comment: The first two ways I can think of is to either handle authentication via session variables, or have a hidden form that submits when you click this link, and authentication information is hidden in this form

Comment: I would say its always advisable not to include credentials in the URL, you  can create a form and use it similar to the POST method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP authentication parameters can be specified in the URL

```
http://username:password@foo.com/foo.mp3
```

Of course, if you put this in the link, anyone who goes to the page can see the authentication information.

Comment: If I'm using angular and the hyperlink is in a directive template, would users still be able to see the authentication information?

Comment: Yes. Even if it's not in the `href` attribute, it will have to be somewhere in the HTML or Javascript, so the user can find it in Develop Tools.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of authorization the site is looking for, and what HTTP method it expects. For example, if it wants an authorization token as a query param via get request, then you would just include that in the link. E.g.

foo.com/foo.mp3?authorization_token=abcd1234

If it expects a session to be established, and it does not redirect a login request back to the original page, then you are going to have some extra work to do:-)